# SWIFT MT field format rules

Tags: documentation, swift-mt

Can someone point me to a document where the formatting rules for a MT message field are described?

For example I want to know what the following snippet means.

> :4!c//3!a/3!a/15d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described in the MT 'General Information' documentation. You can find the 2017 edition of this document [here](https://www2.swift.com/uhbonline/books/public/en_uk/usgi_20170720/usgi.pdf). Specifically, check out section 6.1 for an explanation.

How to read **:4!c//3!a/3!a/15d**:

- first :
- then 4 mandatory c
- then //
- then 3 mandatory a
- then /
- then 3 mandatory a
- then /
- then maximum 15 d

A brief overview of the character types in [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html):

- c is [A-Z0-9]
- a is [A-Z]
- d is \d+,\d*

Answer (score 0):

How to read :4!c//3!a/3!a/15d:

```
first :
then 4!c = must be 4 character "c"
then // is an empty field.
then 3!a = must be 3 character "a"
then /
then 3!a = must be 3 character "a"
then /
then maximum 15d is max 15 character include decimal
```

A brief overview of the character types in regex:

```
c is [A-Z0-9]
a is [A-Z]
d is (0-9) max 15 character include decimal
```

for example :
You will fill price field (90a)

:90B::4!c//4!c/3!a15d

then you can fill = :90B::DEAL//ACTU/EUR1000,5